# How to get a background picture going outside max-width div

Tags: css, html

I have a responsive website with max-width set to 1000px, but I need to fit background picture that will overlap one of the divs and also place full page-width bottom borders to other divs.

The code i have is like this:

```css
.container { 
width: 100%; 
max-width: 1000px;
}


.logotest {
background-color: #03b9e5;
height: 50px;
}

.navtest {
background-color: #e4ed00;
height: 25px;
}

.socialtest {
background-color: #ab801a;
height: 25px;
}

.main {
height: 750px;
background: url(background.jpg) no-repeat top center;
margin: auto;
}

.line {
border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.container:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div class="container" id="first">
<div class="logotest">
</div>
<div class="socialtest">
</div>
<div class="navtest"> 
</div>   
</div>
<div class="line"></div>

<div class="main line" id="second">

</div><div class="container">
<div id="third">
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

I get the first div with correct width and bottom border going across the full page width, second div has got the background picture showing, but the max-width of 1000px does no longer apply. The bottom border is shown correctly (dividing second and third div) and the third div has got the correct max-width applied again.

What am I doing wrong/not doing to get the max-width for the second div?

Comment: have you played with `background-size:cover;` and an outer wrapper?

Comment: the max-width is applied to `container div's`. The second div neither have the class `container` nor a parent container div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**YOUR SOLUTION**

If the browser support of `background-size` property is good enough for you, you can use `background-size: cover;`. Check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/background-size) or [here](http://caniuse.com/#feat=background-img-opts) to see browser support.

Here is the code snippet to show how it works. Be sure to position your background-image to `center center` if you want it to always be centered.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.line {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
.logotest {
  background-color: #03b9e5;
  height: 50px;
}
.navtest {
  background-color: #e4ed00;
  height: 25px;
}
.socialtest {
  background-color: #ab801a;
  height: 25px;
}
.main {
  height: 250px;
  background: url(http://lorempixel.com/250/250) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: cover; /* This does the magic */
}
.container:after {
  clear: both;
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container" id="first">
    <div class="logotest">
    </div>
    <div class="socialtest">
    </div>
    <div class="navtest">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>


  <div class="main" id="second">
    <div class="container">Put your content in here.</div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="third">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="line"></div>
</body>
```

---

**LAST (BUT NOT LEAST)**

You might want to check this great article about the state of responsive images in web design, that will help you if you are going into responsive web design: [Responsive images done right.](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/05/14/responsive-images-done-right-guide-picture-srcset/?utm_content=buffer2944d&utm_medium=social&utm_source=twitter.com&utm_campaign=buffer)

Comment: The first solution doesn't work either. Works similarly to my original solution (second div section using fullscreen width for both image and content) but your solution doesnt give the first bottom line fullscreen width.

Comment: I don't quite understand where you want your bottom lines. Do you want it below your divs with `container` class and `main` class (so that means three lines)? Do you want your lines to be fullscreen even above 1000px width? Can you post a picture to show what you're after please?

Comment: @lomenak I've updated my answer to add lines below `container` and `main` class divs. The line is now fullscreen. I have changed your `max-width` from 1000px to 300px so that you can see if that's what you're after (just replace 300px by 1000px in your code). I have added a `<div class="line"></div>` below each `container` and `main` divs for fullscreen line, is it what you wanted? Also be sure to check the whole code as I made some changes.

Comment: mate this looks like it does exactly what i need. I will test it properly tomorrow morning tho and come back to you!

Comment: Sorry mate I did think of using separate div for the line as well and that does make the line full width however I want to be able to  also have a background image for the main (and third div for that matter) across full width. E.g. i want only all the other content (all but line and background picture) to be affected by the max-width

Comment: Have you tried to understand the code? I have changed my answer to reflect what you need (`main` class div with image being fullscreen). If you need the `third` div to be fullscreen too, just remove the `<div class="container"></div>` wrapping the `third` div.  Now try to understand what the code does, we're not here to solve your problem but to help you understand what you did wrong so that you can improve.

Comment: I do understand the code, this is quite simple example but it still doesnt do what I need. I am sure you dont understand what I actually need to achieve otherwise you wouldnt of given me lecture on what this community does here. I do believe that you guys here want to help people like myself if we get stuck with a code that you may have seen/solved before. I do understand the code you posted but it simply does not help me with my issue. I am trying to get a div that will have background image that spreads outside the div but the content inside the div will be limited to max-width only.

Comment: Get it! Sorry about that, I didn't understand your problem you were right. You can't have an image that spreads outside a div with css, you should use the following structure: `<div class="wrapperwithyourimagefullscreen"><div class="yourcontentthatwillbemax-width"></div></div>"`. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was trying to figure out. I was not sure if there is a CSS method of doing this. I would prefer if this could be done without involving en empty wrapper div, but it will do. Thanks a lot!